# How to change submit button on click to input

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form such a structure:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" />
</form>
```

I need to when you click on the input field changed background submit button. How to do it?

Comment: And what was your attempt in this scenario? Any code you have produced?

Comment: So I tried: 
#searchform input[type='text']:focus #searchsubmit {
    background: url("../images/submit.png") 0 -14px no-repeat;
}
but it dont work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pure CSS solution:

```
input[type="text"]:focus + input[type="submit"]{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/by10et61/

The `+` in the selector is what makes it work. The selector looks for a submit button, which is *preceeded* by a text input having focus.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
$('#s').on('focus',function(){
  $('#searchsubmit').css('background-color','#f00');
}).on('blur',function(){
  $('#searchsubmit').css('background-color','');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example that is easy and clear to understand

**Markup**

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" />
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s').on('focus',function(){
     $('#searchsubmit').css('background-color','red');
  });
});
```

[Working Bin](http://jsbin.com/xubabujevi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Paste the code of your jsbin to the answer. Your answer will become useless if the link stop working, so make sure to put the relevant code as text in it.

Comment: Yeah it does, but what if someone in 6 months has this problem and google duides him here? Will the jsbin link work at this time too? You can´t be sure, so it´s recommended to put the code in the answer.

Comment: @DerVampyr I hear you,but was there any reason to down vote me?

Comment: The reason why you get downvotes is, because your answer is now ok, but maybe be bad in future, so it helps nobody. Just edit your answer and put the code from the jsbin in here and you will lose the downvotes, because your answer will become more useful. Useful link: [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on SO check the "Provide context for links" part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with focus and out function both:

```
$('#s').focus(function(){
    $('#searchsubmit').css('background-color','#f00');
}).focusout(function() {
     //if you get back to other or previous...
    $('#searchsubmit').css('background-color','#ff0');
})
```